# What parameters do I need to pass into this SOAP webservice

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, web-services, soap

In a windows forms app I need to call a SOAP web service (http://www.dat.de:80/GlassRep/services/Authentication?wsdl).

For this WebService I have documentation with some provided samples.

ConsoleApplication:

```
ConsoleApplication1.de.dat.www.VehicleSelection vi = new ConsoleApplication1.de.dat.www.VehicleSelection();
vi.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
string sessionID = vi.doLogin("123456789",
                "username1",
                "akEwRUF3TUM45678Gd5U2NxdHdlKzBaQTF4QVBIT21DVXpRPQ==");
Console.WriteLine("sessionID = " + sessionID);
```

but when I call the WebService:

```
Dim authService As New WebServiceTest.Authentication
    authService.doLogin(
```

Method doLogin needs a parameter WebServiceTest.doLoginRequest(), and so is for all methods.

Why the Method doLogin doesn't have as parameter 3 strings but have doLoginRequest()?

What do I need to change or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doLogin` method is expecting a parameter of type `doLoginRequest`.  I did not test this, since I do not have authorization to access their service, nor do I know what it does. But this is what I gleen that you need to do.

```
Dim auth As New de.dat.www.Authentication()
Dim req As New de.dat.www.doLoginRequest()
req.customerNumber = "123456789"
req.customerLogin = "username1"
req.customerSignature = "akEwRUF3TUM45678Gd5U2NxdHdlKzBaQTF4QVBIT21DVXpRPQ=="
auth.doLogin(req)
```

I made some assumptions about the values supplied to the request parameters.  You'll need to verify with the documentation or with the firm to make sure those are correct.  There's also `interfacePartnerNumber` and `interfacePartnerSignature` which I did not supply here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like when you call doLogin() you don't have an option to pass in 3 strings? Is this perhaps an overloaded method with more options?

I don't think you have enough code here for anyone to help for what you have tried.

It looks like you need to declare a website first for authService to work.

Comment: I included WebService in MyProject: 
Project -> Enter a service reference -> Extended -> add Webreference and this Method doesn't have overloaded methods...

Comment: I don't understand how that is possible but I do not think anyone on SO can help? I could be wrong but this is more of a development problem.

They gave you a method, showed you how to do it with an example, and the example doesn't work..

Comment: If you call a method, and the method doesn't accept the parameters shown in the example, I have no idea what to do differently. Check and make sure in the rest of the example that they haven't done something to make the doLogin() possible, but overall it seems like a development problem